# Delete the first file in a folder if the length of a folder is more than the limit

Tags: python, arrays, list, delete-file, os.path

- First I created a folder that contains Images named as 1.jpg till 20.jpg
- Now I want to loop through this folder and add all these images into a list/array.
- I keep checking the length of this array/list and if the length is more than say 20 then the first image file should be deleted

I am able to delete the first element of the array of Images but I am not knowing how to delete the actual Image in the path of the folder

CODE BELOW

import cv2

import glob

import numpy as np

images = [19]

files = glob.glob ("./output/*.jpg")

for x in files:

if len(images) >= 19:
image_array.pop();

```
    print("removed first element")

else:

    image = cv2.imread(x)

    image_array.append(images) #append each image to array

    print("no issues")
```

print('image_array shape:', np.array(images).shape)

cv2.imshow('frame', image_array[0])

cv2.waitKey(0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be helpful: https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-remove-a-file-if-exists-and-handle-errors-os-remove-os-ulink/

```
import os
# Remove a file
os.remove('/home/somedir/Documents/python/logs')
```

In your case:

```
files_list = ["/home/somedir/img1.jpg", "/home/somedir/img2.jpg", ...]
if len(files_list) > 20:
    os.remove(files_list[0])
    del files_list[0]
```

Comment: We answered at the same time! Funny how there is such great competition on these questions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the issue here is it is going to be a dynamic set of images getting refreshed . So the name of the first file is not always going to be the same . Let's say that now it is 1.jpg , it can be 2.jpg after a second . So my code should specifically target only the first image irrespective of it's name

Comment: Yeah, funny timing issue :)

Comment: zeke wonder - Please check the updates answer

Comment: @EvinlorthDGreat for the variable files_list that you have given instead of writing each file name with it's path can I use the following lines of code :

path = '/home/Desktop/output/' 
files = os.listdir(path)

Answer (score -1):

From Grepper: `os.remove("demofile.txt")`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the issue here is it is going to be a dynamic set of images getting refreshed . So the name of the first file is not always going to be the same . Let's say that now it is 1.jpg , it can be 2.jpg after a second . So my code should specifically target only the first image irrespective of it's name

Comment: Well, then I recommend `os.remove(files[0])`

Comment: `import cv2

import glob

import numpy as np
import os


path = '/home/Desktop/output/'
files = os.listdir(path)
print(len(files))

if len(files) > 20:
    os.remove(files[0])
    del files[0]

print(len(files))`

I used this code but it is not deleting the exact first file . It is randomly deleting the files in between @norway-yv

Comment: Hmm. Well, it should work, as what I recommended was the same as what Evinlorth DFreat recommended. Perhaps there is some typo? I don't know.

Comment: I've found that glob() returns the files in no particular order and hence we can sort it out using sorting method attaching to glob. Thank you for response :)